# i18next: fallback to [same language + different namespace] instead of [different language + same namespace]

Tags: node.js, i18next

This is about using i18next in a node.js backend.
This is the initialization:

```
i18next.init({
    lng: 'de',
    fallbackLng: ['de'],
    ns: {
        namespaces: ['formal', 'informal'],
        defaultNs: 'formal'
    },
    fallbackToDefaultNS: true,

    resStore: {
        de: resourcesDE,
        en: resourcesEN
    }
});
```

where resourcesDE is an object with structure { formal: {  }, informal: {  }} and resourcesEN has the same structure but only 'formal', no 'informal' (but I have this problem even if there is 'informal' in resourcesEN).

Now, what I **want** to have is:

If I request the translation of 'informal:myKey' for English that the search route (== fallback) is:

(en)'informal:myKey' > (en)'myKey' > (de)'informal:myKey' > (de)'myKey'
or
(en)'informal:myKey' > (en)'myKey' > (de)'myKey'

but what **actually** happens is:

(en)'informal:myKey' > (de)'informal:myKey' > (de)'myKey'

meaning that the language changes before even trying to get a text of the same language from a different (the default) namespace.

How can I achieve this or something along those lines. I've also tried using a context instead of namespaces for these alternatives, but that seemed to behave the same. I'm glad to be proven wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked out for me, in the end:

Instead of namespaces, I use special language flavors: 'de-INFORMAL' and 'en-INFORMAL'. If no label is found under 'en-INFORMAL', the lookup falls back to 'en', first and out of the box. If `fallbackLng` is set to 'de' it will fallback to that if the label in not found in 'en', either.